# RViz marker coordinate space

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was wondering what coordinate space RViz markers work in (Pose or Points parameters).

I have an object with Pose of 5000, 5000, 0, however when I open RViz and draw a Marker with 0, 0, 0 coordinate, it draws it directly over the object.

What's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325189/rviz-marker-coordinate-space/) by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2019-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RVIZ markers specify their frame_id in the message, along with their pose. So if you specify a point at (0, 0, 0) then it will be shown at the origin of the given pose defined within the coordinate system of '<frame_id>'

I usually set the pose to identity to keep things simple, and calculate the marker points directly within the specified frame, but that isn't always appropriate.

Regarding the problem you describe can you post a screen-shot along with the code which produces it. We'll just be guessing without it.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-06-10**:
Awesome, thank you!

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-06-10**:
I solved it, my TF was incorrect!

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-06-10**:
Glad you got it working.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-11**:
Just a follow-up comment: everything in ROS *should* use (derived) SI units. So metres, kilograms, etc.

This applies to `Marker` messages as well.